# Magento 2 on local host with XAMPP

Tags: magento2, localhost, apache, xampp

I am trying to transfer my live site to a local host on my PC, I did the following:

All the website's files are in `C:\xampp\htdocs\html`. I also imported the database and changed **env.php** and **web/secure/url** and **web/unsecure/url** (to **127.0.0.1/html**). The problem is that there are errors in the code where **`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`** is being used.

I tried changing inside `httpd.conf` the document root from

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/html"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/html">
```

And the result was that my site was showing, but all pages are 404.

Am I missing something? maybe some DB configuration or Magento's file for local environment?

thanks.

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite module is installed in your local server. You can check using phpinfo() fucntion.

Comment: @Hezided Did you tried to install Magento on your local server is it compatible with your local configuration?

Comment: @IrfanMomin yes it's uncommented in httpd.conf.@ABHISHEK TRIPATHI not sure I understand your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually what worked for me was to move all the files to separate folder (C:/myFolder), and change the DocumentRoot to there...
also values of:

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_link_url
web/secure/base_link_url
```

is http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed your **DocumentRoot** to "C:/xampp/htdocs/html", then your **web/unsecure/url** entry will be "*http://127.0.0.1/*" .

Change this entry in database and clear the cache. It should work for you.

Comment: I still get "page not found" everywhere...

Comment: can you please share the sceenshot of the browser page including the url

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0tBzc
the marked string means "page not found"

Comment: If you'll check the url in browser, it is http://127.0.0.1/html it should be http://127.0.0.1/ then it will load the homepage.

Comment: yes it's true, but then if I click any link in my site the 'html' is added, for example: http://127.0.0.1/html/sack-bags.html/

Comment: have you cleared the cache ? and what is the value in web/unsecure/url ?

Comment: yes I cleared the cache, the value is 'http://127.0.0.1/'